# How does one keep track of all of the different statuses, conditions, and mathematically-entwined stats of FFRPG?

Tags: conditions, final-fantasy-rpg

Returner Games’s FFRPG has, to my mind, a very serious flaw in that it forgets that, unlike the video game consoles that you run *Final Fantasy* games on, tabletop games don’t have a computer keeping track and updating all of the numbers for us.

As a result, there are a *lot* of different conditions, most of which affect multiple stats, and most stats affect yet more stats, often in complicated ways.

So how does one attempting to play this game keep track of all of those?

Comment: I am curious to know if you're comfortable with players using excel (i.e laptops) to track their characters as well as all of the temporary effects affecting them. I create all of my characters using an excel template I developed and as a consequence, I'm generally the one who tracks whatever for the GM. The spin off benefits are immediately noticeable as I never have to take more than a second to calculate my damage, to hit, buffs, debuffs, etc. and you can build in whatever temporary modifiers you need to. While I've only made templates for my D&D characters, you're more than welcome to them

Comment: @silversociety My feeling is that an RPG shouldn't require those (and indeed, D&D doesn't necessarily though it does help). But with FFRPG, I haven't found any other answer, it just seems like something of a cop-out.

Answer (score 5):

My best method is this: Give everyone a sheet of plastic (like you would get in sheet covers, twenty for a dollar where I am), and a dry erase marker.  Have them put tic marks next to a status' duration and its effect right under it, and they can use their finger to erase tic marks when their turn gets to them.  There is a wide enough margin on the sheet to list a "Current Stat" column and once a status is added/removed, simply erase with a finger or napkin and rewrite the new value.

Edit 1: Please note, you can easily slice the seam and have a two page wide "display" of current stats without having to damage the char sheet.  I have had limited success (mostly due to not having fine enough markers) in just overlaying the char sheet.